# Is create job only way to execute BigQuery select query from Java ? For this I need to have BigQuery Job User permission. Is there another way?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there an alternate Java code to execute BigQuery select query to fetch some data instead of through a job. Below is my code where I am creating jobid and then executing the query. Looking for some other options.

```
try {
            GoogleCredentials credentials;
            String keyPath = "Path_to_json.json";
            File credentialsPath = new File(keyPath);
            FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath);
                credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);


            // Instantiate a client.
            BigQuery bigquery =
                  BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();

            QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
                    QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(
                            "select * from `bigquery-public-data`.new_york_subway.stations)
                            .setUseLegacySql(false)
                            .build();

            // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
            JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Job queryJob=
                       bigquery.create(
                             JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

            // Wait for the query to complete.
            queryJob = queryJob.waitFor();

            // Check for errors
            if (queryJob == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Job no longer exists");
            } else if (queryJob.getStatus().getError() != null) {
                // You can also look at queryJob.getStatus().getExecutionErrors() for all
                // errors, not just the latest one.
                throw new RuntimeException(queryJob.getStatus().getError().toString());
            }

            // Get the results.
            TableResult result = queryJob.getQueryResults();

            // Print all pages of the results.
            for (FieldValueList row : result.iterateAll()) {
                String stationId = row.get("station_id").getStringValue();
                String stationName  = row.get("station_name").getStringValue();
                System.out.println("StationId : "+stationId+"      Station Name : 
                    "+stationName);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: 1) What roles do you have for BigQuery? Your probably want `roles/bigquery.user` 2) Try executing the query in the console. 3) Are you the project owner or editor? 4) If you do not have any BiqQuery permission, then you will need to ask for them or assign them yourself to your identity.

Comment: I have appropriate role to view BigQuery data and above code also working fine. Its just that what I want is that is there any other way in java to fetch BigQuery select data instead of creating the Job how it is happening in the above code example ?

Comment: I don't write code for BigQuery in Java, but I do in C#. I just create a BigQuery Client and then call ExecuteQuery(). Most likely a similar API exists for Java.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery supports two types of queries:

- Interactive queries
- Batch queries

**Interactive** queries are the ones set by default. These queries are executed as soon as possible. On the other hand, **batch** queries will start the query execution as soon as idle resources are available.

Regarding your question "*Is create job only way to execute BigQuery select query from Java ? For this I need to have BigQuery Job User permission. Is there another way?*" you have to take into consideration that **both of those queries will necessarily create a query job** and to do you will require the BigQuery Job User role. You will find more information on Java Client library for BigQuery in [this](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/index.html?com/google/cloud/bigquery/package-summary.html) reference and more information on BigQuery roles and permissions in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control).

Answer (score 0):

We can extract result data from GBQ without Job. It seems job could be useful when we also have some retry logic in place.

```java
public static void queryLargeResults(String destinationDataset,
                                     String destinationTable,
                                     String query) {
    try {
        // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
        // once, and can be reused for multiple requests.
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
        // To use legacy SQL syntax, set useLegacySql to true.
               QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                                    .setUseLegacySql(true)
                                    // Save the results of the query to a permanent table.
                                    .setDestinationTable(TableId.of(destinationDataset, destinationTable))
                                    // Allow results larger than the maximum response size.
                                    // If true, a destination table must be set.
                                    .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                                    .build();

        TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
        results.iterateAll()
               .forEach(row -> row.forEach(val -> System.out.printf("%s,", val.toString())));
        System.out.println("Query large results performed successfully.");
    } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Query not performed \n" + e.toString());
    }
}
```

This is google code snippet: https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/main/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/QueryLargeResults.java